# How to send email with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The application has no problem, I do not change the configuration.
A month later i tried the program gets an error.

Error messages :

> Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 269: Connection
>   could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]

This configuration of the env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mr.xxxxxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

This configuration of mail.php :

```
<?php
return [

'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),

'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),

'from' => ['address' => 'muhamadramadhan95@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Ramadhan'],

'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'ssl'),

'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

];
```

Please help, thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried changing the encryption to `tls`? Use `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`and port `MAIL_PORT=587` Let me know if this works!

Comment: @HirenGohel Okay I will try.

Comment: which protocol you are using and http or https

Comment: @HirenGohel did not work:(

Comment: Do this: `$php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: @VedPrakash I'm still in the local web , before no problem.

Comment: @HirenGohel I've tried but could not.

Comment: but you are using gmail server or requesting to gmail server and Gmail accept only https.... |||||| http work before but now a days only https

Comment: try using `mailgun`

Comment: @SitiRahmah I am not sure may be possibility

Comment: You need to use `mailgun` then!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `mailgun`. Here i've post the steps to use it:

**Step 1:**
Get the Mailgun API, Sign up to Mailgun, Add Your Domain

**Step 2:** Configure Laravel Application

In your `config/services.php` file, add the following:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
],
```

Next, you will need to go to your `.env` file, and replace the `“MAIL_USERNAME”`, `“MAIL_PASSWORD”`, `“MAILGUN_DOMAIN”` AND `“MAILGUN_SECRET”` with your own.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@yourdomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=yourmailgunpassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

MAILGUN_DOMAIN=yourdomain.com
MAILGUN_SECRET=key-YourMailGunSecret
```

Last step, in the same file, you will need to also add, and replace the value with your own:

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS: hello@yourdomain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME: John
```

That's it! Hope this will helps you!

Comment: It's been working, but eventually I tried webmail with mine.
Thank you've helped, mailgun also works. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use sendgrid. Its very simple.

***step-1:***
Add SendGrid to your **composer.json**

```
"require":  
{ 
"sendgrid/sendgrid": "~6.0"
}
```

***step-2:***

in .env file set your sendgrid api key

```
SENDGRID_API_KEY= Your Sendgrid API key
```

***step-3:***

Add following code in your controller

```
$from = new \SendGrid\Email(null, "your email id");//place senders email id
                        $subject = "checking Email service"; //*your subject goes here*
                        $to = new \SendGrid\Email("Example User", 'example@gmail.com');  //*place reciever email id*
                        $content = new \SendGrid\Content("text/html", $otp);
                        $mail = new \SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

                        $apiKey = env('SENDGRID_API_KEY');// set in .env file
                        $sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

                        $response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
                        return json_encode(['code' => 200, 'status' => 'Success', 'message' => 'mail sent Sucessfully]);
```

for better understanding follow below link

```
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try changing `encryption` and `port` in your `.env` file:**

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_PORT=587
```

**and then run:**

```
$php artisan config:clear
```

**Or, If that doesn't work either then try the hack below:**

Add the following lines to `_establishSocketConnection()` method in `Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php` on line 263:

```
$options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;

$options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;
```

***Note:*** The hack specified above is just a workaround and could be overwritten anytime the `Swift` package updates. So keep that in mind if you try to use this method.

Comment: I got a new problem after adding the code.

stream_socket_enable_crypto (): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error: 14090086: SSL routines: ssl3_get_server_certificate: certificate verify failed

Comment: @SitiRahmah: You solved the problem disabling the antivirus if you used any! Hope it fixed this.